# How to access variable outside click event or context

Tags: javascript, closures, dom-events

I'm trying to access the `NewUrl` variable in the LaunchPopup function when `chat online` is clicked.

My Chrome debugger can see the variable in closure after the click event. I've also tried binding the variable to this, but the variable remains `undefined`.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(‘.link '), function (doc) {

     doc.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var uniqueID = 'unique data';
      var NewUrl = Url.split("&response_type")[0] + encodeURIComponent("&uniqueID=" + uniqueID);
     });
     
     if (doc != null) {
      window.LaunchPopup = function() {
       var self = this;
       n = window.open(self.NewUrl, '_blank', 'width=450,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
       return openPopup = n == null ? true : false;
      };
      
      doc.innerHTML = '<a href="' + Url + '" class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" onclick="return LaunchPopup();">Chat online</a>';
     }
    });
```

Help and some explainer is appreciated why the variable can't be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to refactor it a bit by splitting the `if` statement into its own function. Then, pass in the `doc` and the `NewUrl` into the function.

You will need to move out `window.LaunchPopup` to be more widely scoped as well and have calls to it pass in `this`.

Finally I put `newURL` in a `data-` attribute so we can access it via `this` when the anchor tag is clicked

Here is an example.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.link '), function(doc) {

  doc.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var uniqueID = 'unique data';
    var newUrl = Url.split("&response_type")[0] + encodeURIComponent("&uniqueID=" + uniqueID);
    showPop(doc, NewUrl);
  });
});

function showPop(doc, theURL) {
  if (doc != null) {
    doc.innerHTML = '<a href="' + theURLUrl + '" data-new-url="' + newURL + '" class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" onclick="return LaunchPopup(this);">Chat online</a>';
  }
}

window.LaunchPopup = function(anchor) {
  var newUrl = anchor.getAttribute("data-new-url");
  var self = this;
  var n = window.open(newUrl, '_blank', 'width=450,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
  return openPopup = n == null ? true : false;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this approach.

Comment: is there another way to solve this? a setTimeout() and onstateready() wraps everything such that when the document loads, it injects this line `kia.innerHTML = ...` into the document. showPop() runs only `onclick`.

Comment: @nara_l you can call showPop from anywhere, just call it where you need to (as long as `doc` isn't null, it will work)

Comment: it does not work as expected. doc.innerHTML is not injected into the DOM onreadystate. When I move the line so it gets injected, the window.LaunchPopup() is not found.

Comment: Okay I updated my answer, you can send `this` through to a more widely scoped LaunchPopup function, the function can read the href property of the anchor tag that was clicked and pull theUrl out form there

Comment: Thanks for the update. This almost worked, apart from the fact that `theUrl` and `theNewUrl` are supposed to be different - confirmed after testing. Your implementation in LaunchPopup() means theUrl would be the same as theNewURL.

Comment: okay I think this edit should do it. I did not notice `Url` since I didn't see it defined in your example. In my update I put the `newURL` in a `data`- attribute on the anchor tag - so it can be accessed when clicked via `this`. The `href` attribute is still the previous `Url` in this case too. I also realized the `showPop` function was unnecessary so I removed it to clean up the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, looking at it, I think it may not work because this line `   if (doc != null) {...}` inside the click event block. It is outside the click event but within the forEach, reason why there is trouble accessing `theNewUrl` in the first place.

Comment: Okay you can just move it outside the click event function. The showPop is needed I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare the newurl variable directly in the foreach callback, that way both event listeners can access it.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(‘.link '), function (doc) {

     var NewUrl;

     doc.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var uniqueID = 'unique data';
      NewUrl = Url.split("&response_type")[0] + encodeURIComponent("&uniqueID=" + uniqueID);
     });
     
     if (doc != null) {
      window.LaunchPopup = function() {
       var self = this;
       n = window.open(NewUrl, '_blank', 'width=450,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
       return openPopup = n == null ? true : false;
      };
      
      doc.innerHTML = '<a href="' + Url + '" class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" onclick="return LaunchPopup();">Chat online</a>';
     }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @james, I'll have to test this. I believe I tried this implementation the variable remained not defined. Would test again in a couple of hours.

Comment: so NewUrl is undefined when the popup launches

Answer (score 0):

Had to make changes to the implementation and this worked ok.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(‘.link '), function (doc) {

     doc.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var uniqueID = 'unique data';
      var NewUrl = Url.split("&response_type")[0] + encodeURIComponent("&uniqueID=" + uniqueID);
      var n = window.open(NewUrl, '_blank', 'width=450,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
      if(n == null) {
          return true;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
     });
     
     if (doc != null) {
           
      doc.innerHTML = '<a href="' + Url + '" class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" ">Chat online</a>';
     }
    });
```